# How to loop through words with conditions

Tags: python, loops

Your task is to write a program that loops through the words in the provided jane_eyre.txt file and counts those words which fulfill both of the following conditions:

The word has more than 10 characters
The word does not contain the letter "e"
Once you've finished the aggregation, let your program print out the following message:
There are 10 long words without an 'e'.

My work:

```
count = 0

f = open("jane_eyre.txt").read()

words = f.split()

if len(words) > 10 and "e" not in words:

   count += 1

print("There are", count, "long words without an 'e'.")
```

The count result is 1 but it should be 10. What's wrong with my work??

Comment: You need to use `for loop` on list of words

Comment: have you tried `print(words)` ? always print a variable when using it doesn't give the expected thing

Comment: "write a program that loops through the words" Your program doesn't even attempt to loop through words at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate on each word, with best practice:

```
with open('jane_eyre.txt') as fp:  # use a context manager
    count = 0  # initialize counter to 0
    for word in fp.read().split():  # for each word
        if len(word) > 10 and not 'e' in word:  # your condition
            count += 1  # increment counter
    print(f"There are {count} long words without an 'e'.")  # use f-strings
```

But **pay attention to punctuation**: "imaginary," is 10 characters length but the word itself has only 9 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each word. So something like:

```
count = 0

f = open("jane_eyre.txt").read()

words = f.split()

for word in words:
    if len(word) > 10 and "e" not in word:
    
       count += 1

print("There are", count, "long words without an 'e'.")
```